# Disable startup scripts when loging in?

Tags: startup

In Windows you press the shift key when you login to disable any startup scripts from running. Is there an equivalent action in Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

There are 2 sorts of scripts:

- scripts that are started as part of the system and affect all users.
- scripts that are started when you log in as part of your own session.

Both do not have a keyboard switch to turn them off or on on the fly.

Comment: Makes sense as Linux is more security focused

Answer (score 0):

Go to dash and search startup, some are hidden for security reasons so in the terminal type this

sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=false/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop

And then try the startup application.

Comment: Is this change then forever?

Comment: Yes just like msconfig in windows you will have to re enable them to run at start up.

Comment: Will give it a go

Comment: Ok post your findings.

Comment: How does this disable scripts? It just makes the links visible!

Comment: You can disable start up apps in the startup app. The terminal just displays hidden startup.